# How to visualize this geometric setup?

Tags: geometry

I am working on a derivation (physics) and the first part requires one to imagine a geometric setup. Since I'm not a native speaker of the language, I am having trouble in doing so. The relevant portion is given below:

> Establish a minuscule area dA on the interface and establish two angular coordinates. We measure the polar angle θ with respect to a line drawn perpendicular to dA and the azimuthal angle φ with respect to an arbitrary circle lying parallel to dA. Consider only those vapor molecules that float arbitrarily close to the interface and that have velocities v with speeds in the range between v and v+dv oriented in directions whose angular coordinates lie between θ and θ+dθ and between φ and φ+dφ.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: See this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262515/how-to-visualize-this-setup-for-deriving-frac-dmdt-while-water-is-evapora/262550?noredirect=1#comment581445_262550

Comment: I've seen and the answer looks very clear to me. What's wrong then?

Comment: The figure is alright, but what does the vector represent, is it the velocity or the distance (how far are the vapor molecules from the $dA$)?

Comment: It represents velocity: that is the phycal quantity of interest here.